# How to specify position of an image in a grid through code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

the thing that we do in xaml like this

```
        <Image Height="136" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="/XYZ;component/Images/140-90.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="mouseLeftButtonDown_Image1">
```

i am doing something like this so how to define the position like 
Grid.Row="0", Grid.Column="0" inside the following block. suppose i have to get a
reference of Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" in the code which is where this control is going to be placed

```
        Image img = new Image()
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(backImageUri[1].ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            Width = 200,
            Height = 136,

        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Grid.Row="0"` and `Grid.Column="0"` are attached properties, so you can use next code to assign some value:

```
image.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
```